# Is there a politically correct way to speak about reproductive health, justice, etc., which doesn't unnecessarily gender the issue?

Tags: grammatical-gender, gender-neutral, political-correctness, gender-politics, sexual-minorities

Most cisgender women, some intersex people of different variations, most transgender men, some AFAB non-binary people, and most people who are assigned females on the whole are usually the ones who need access to things such as abortion, birth control, etc., but the language that we use in English with regard to the people who need these things are, in my estimation, too often unnecessarily gendered as "feminine" or "female".

This is problematic because not every person who needs these types of procedures or treatments is a woman or a girl, so how can we, without being too wordy, or sounding like too much of a pedant or anything de-gender the issues of abortion and access thereof, birth control and the like?

Comment: Focus on the need for access to these products and services, and not the set of people who need access to them?

Comment: There is no politically correct way to be politically correct.  Someone will always object.

Comment: @DanBron Can you provide me with an example? How, for instance, could one speak about abortion and access thereof for all people, not just women and girls, in a way which doesn't gender the practice of abortion as "female" or "feminine"?

Comment: @EnglishLearner “abortion should accessible”, “everyone who needs it should have access to abortion”, “abortion shouldn’t be restricted”, “people must be able to get abortions’, and 10 trillion other ways. You don’t want to refer to gender; so don’t.

Comment: @DanBron As one can infer from my name on here, I am an English learner, so my speaking and writing skills are still a little poor, but from what I understand could one make, say, the noun "abortion" the subject of the sentence so that by implication everyone to whom abortion is applicable can be included in it?

Comment: @DanBron Plus, another issue on which I wanted to touch was pregnancy and genital language. I often unconsciously refer to pregnancy with feminine or female terms, and I often refer to genitalia, chromosomes, hormones, etc., as "female" or "male". How can these two things with which I am struggling be de-gendered so that every gender is included?

Comment: @EnglishLearner Did I not already demonstrate that? I am not able to see the difficulty here. You either talk about abortion without reference to people, or you refer to people without reference to gender. Same with pregnancy. Genitalia you’re going to have a much harder time with; I’d simply stick with “penis” and “vagina”. I must imagine you are familiar in your every day English usage with such constructions, native speaker, learner, or any other. By the way, the site dedicated to learning English as a second language is [ell.se].

Comment: You’re confusing sex and gender.

Comment: @Xanne, How so? I understand sex as the biological things with which a person is born, e.g. one's chromosomes, the hormones one releases at puberty, the genitals one has at birth, the gonads had, etc., and gender is the roles which are assigned to one based off of the genital group of which one is part, no? That is how I understand the sex and gender distinction. Perhaps that has not shown in my questions or answers, but that is how I understand them. If there is a problem, then I have probably given that impression die to my still being an English learner.

Comment: @EnglishLearner Re your last comment, aren't you actually using "gender" synonymously with "gender identity" in your question, rather than "gender role" as your comment seems to imply?

Comment: Is there any objection to calling them "people"?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is primarily going to be one of opinion.  So, I hesitate to answer it.

However, speaking as a medical professional, the workaround being used to avoid the linguistic gymnastics of inclusiveness is:  **assigned female at birth**.

For example, Truvada a drug for HIV prevention was initially not approved in patients [assigned female at birth](https://www.lgbtqnation.com/2019/10/fda-just-approved-new-drug-prevent-hiv-transmission/).

By using this blanket statement, you're able to include anyone who needs access to medical procedures that affect their present at birth sex organs regardless of their gender identity.